# jupyter RISE, hide Image command

Tags: image, jupyter, rise

I use RISE on Jupyter notebook for creating a slide show. In a cell intended to show images with:

```
Image('./pics/iris.png', width='100%')
```

I want to hide the command in the slide show and just show the image. Is there a way?

Answer (score 0):

I think a change to Jupyter markdown makes it.

```
<img src=".\pics\iris.png"/
```